# Cannot exclude particular post from loop of custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, exclude

I have a custom post type (from a theme installed by previous developer), and here is the code of loop which retrieve the post and display them.

```
<?php
// Counter
$post_count = 1;

// Query
$gp_query_args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'event',

    //EXCLUDE Events try by me
    'post__not_in' => array('1646'),
    // exclude event try code block ends

    'meta_key'          => 'gp_event_date',
    'meta_value'        => date('Y/m/d'),
    'meta_compare'      => '>=',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1

);
$gp_query = NULL;
$gp_query = new WP_Query($gp_query_args);
```

I want to exclude certain events (post of custom post type, from loop), and as you can see i tried using `'post__not_in' => array('1646'),` where `1646` is the post id i see when i edit the custom post . So i guess this is universal post id, not custom post type specific id.   But No Matter, the post is not being excluded :-(

Am i doing wrong??

### Edit1:

I found a [repository on github](links below edit3 )
 that is exactly similar to my theme structure. 
I don't know the theme name, so i'm not sure whether that's the same theme on the site i'm working over.

### Edit2

So as per the suggestions below

I did, renamed template-event.php (my template file for showing list of events  ) to `archive-event.php`

And placed the function [snippet from here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/177383/9884) in function.php of my theme.

But i cannot exclude the post with specified ID yet.

**Edit3**

As asked here is the link of the github repository  that is exactly same as my theme.

Github Links:

- [template-event.php](https://github.com/tiffanytse/breadbyus-wordpress/blob/master/linguini/template-event.php)
- [posttype-event.php](https://github.com/tiffanytse/breadbyus-wordpress/blob/master/linguini/backend/posttypes/posttype-event.php)

Comment: Add your CPT code as an EDIT above.

Comment: Hi added the github links. By  CPT code, you mean the code registering the post type right?? (posttype-event.php)

Comment: The problem is with your code. Add this parameter 'has_archive'  => true,

Comment: If you EVER republish anyone else's work, always include a link as per SE policy http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. I had a look at your `template-event.php`, and the alarming thing is that it uses `query_posts` which you should never ever use. You should change that. Also, echo the SQL request (`echo $gp_query->request`) and check if the SQL is correctly build, and make double sure your ID is correct

Comment: Also, to exclude that the error is caused by custom filters, add `'suppress_filters'=>true` to your arguments

Comment: @BradDalton i didn't even now understood what was wrong in my question. I just provided github links?? SE Policy is out of my mind .. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work from your functions file as long as you use the correct conditional tag for your CPT archive:

```
function exclude_single_post_cpt($query) {
  if (is_post_type_archive('event') && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
    $query->set('post__not_in', array(1646));
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_single_post_cpt');
```

Comment: well yes. my cpt is 'event'. still this code dosn't work :-(
 
I added the function snippt at the end of my function.php
thanks

Comment: Exclude from CPT archive loop or home page ( posts page )?

Comment: exclude from the page that shows list of posts of the type = event. The template file name is - `template-event.php`

The structure and code is exactly same as the given github link. 

regards

Comment: i just read the codex, i guess my case isn't for archive. 

Thats a simple template just like the homepage template which queries post of the cpt type, an display a list of them. 

Ur thoughts??

Comment: Yes, it should be archive-event.php,  so the code works but the conditional doesn't because your file name is wrong. Change the file name and the code will work or add another file using the correct name according to the WordPress Template Hierarchy.

Comment: Or try and replace is_post_type_archive('event') with is_page_template('event')

Comment: tried both way, (renaming to archive-event.php ), as well as replacing is_post_type_archive with is_page_template , neiher works. 

Cant i pass the post id in query itself to exclude that post while retriving post list?? 

Anyway none of these methods are working .. :-(

Comment: My code is tested and works. Cannot continue to extend this discussion because of forum rules. Please check ALL "YOUR" code.

Comment: Finally i got that working. Rechecking the code and adding the function in function.php fixed finally. 

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should rename your file `archive-event.php` instead of `template-event.php` as per the WordPress Theme Hierarchy. The `template-event.php` (`template-customposttypename.php`) file used for display the content of single events as the `single.php` working to display the content of post content.

You can use your above code by using any page template also. I hope it will be work.